# Set grid to fill the whole screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I feel dumb for asking this, but how can I set a grid to use the whole space of my wpf page ? I can't seem to put its height to "*" and I'd like it to fill the whole "DesignHeight/Width" as I change them. Thank you !

```
<Page x:Class="Aud10.MenuHome"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MenuHome" d:DesignHeight="860" d:DesignWidth="1196">
    <Grid Height="860" Width="1196">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.333*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.333*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.333*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I think w.b's solution should do what you want! But one comment for you: If you want both rows to have the same height, you don't need to declare it explicitly ("The GridLength that represents the height of the row.The default value is 1.0.", https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.height(v=vs.110).aspx). Just write <RowDefinition /> twice to get two rows sharing 50% of the space each (same for the ColumDefinition).

Comment: oh you're right ! thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the `Width` and `Height` settings altogether, then the `Grid` will fill up all available space automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Label" Width="150" />
    <TextBox Text="Value" Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
```